# Can python mechanize handle HTTP auth?

Tags: python, mechanize

Mechanize (Python) is failing with 401 for me to open http digest URLs. I googled and tried debugging but no success.

My code looks like this.

```
import mechanize

project = "test"
baseurl = "http://trac.somewhere.net"
loginurl = "%s/%s/login" % (baseurl, project)
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.add_password(baseurl, "user", "secret", "some Realm")
b.open(loginurl)
```

Comment: What does failing mean? Is it failing with a 403? Some other error or condition?

Comment: Is trac configured to check with HTTP authentication? Or do you have to login over a simple HTML form?

Comment: Something looks odd - you appear to be navigating to a login page, which one normally wouldn't expected to be protected. With basic/digest auth you go straight to the protected resource, providing your credentials in the HTTP headers (which mechanize does for you, of course).

Answer (score 6):

Mechanize claims that the parameters should be uri, username and password as parameters, but you have four parameters. Four parameters are correct for urllib2.add_password, but then the first parameter should be the realm, not the uri.

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

I'd try to change that first.

Does trac require digest? if not a next step could be to try using basic auth, as a test to see if that works, since you can add that with just addHeader:

```
import base64
from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()
browser.addheaders.append(('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, pwd))))
```

Comment: The last parameter is optional: realm, defaulting to None.

Comment: Ah, OK. Never seen that one, and docs doesn't mention it... But anyway, you catched the fact that he was only opening the login screen, so this is in fact not an authentication error at all.

Comment: help -> add_password(self, url, user, password, realm=None) method of mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance

Secondly similar script using Twill works well. Twill in turn uses mechanize only.

Answer (score 4):

For http authentication with mechanize you need to provide the complete url to the `add_password` method and not just the host base address.

```
import mechanize

project = "test"
baseurl = "http://trac.somewhere.net"
loginurl = "%s/%s/login" % (baseurl, project)
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.add_password(loginurl, "user", "secret", "some Realm")
b.open(loginurl)
```

Comment: For others' reference, this has either changed or seems not to be the case. Providing `baseurl` in this instance, at least for mechanize 0.3.3, appears to result in all URLs starting with that exact baseurl using the specified credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import mechanize

a=mechanize.Browser()
a.open("http://www.facebook.com/login.php")
a.select_form(nr=0)  #form number.
a["email"]="mailaddress"
a["pass"]="password"
a.submit()
print a
```

Comment: This is not for http authentication. This is when the page you are loging into has a form on the page. Http authentication does not have a form